# Euclidean distance between two n-dimensional vectors

Tags: julia, euclidean-distance

What's an easy way to find the Euclidean distance between two n-dimensional vectors in Julia?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is a simple way

```
n = 10
x = rand(n)
y = rand(n)
d = norm(x-y)  # The euclidean (L2) distance
```

For Manhattan/taxicab/L1 distance, use `norm(x-y,1)`

Comment: In Julia 1.0 you have to call `using LinearAlgebra` first.

Answer (score 14):

This is easily done thanks to the lovely [Distances](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distances.jl) package:

```
Pkg.add("Distances") #if you don't have it
using Distances
one7d = rand(7)
two7d = rand(7)
dist = euclidean(one7d,two7d)
```

Also if you have say 2 matrices of 9d col vectors, you can get the distances between each corresponding pair using colwise:

```
thousand9d1 = rand(9,1000)
thousand9d2 = rand(9,1000)
dists = colwise(Euclidean(), thousand9d1, thousand9d2)
#returns: 1000-element Array{Float64,1}
```

You can also compare to a single vector e.g. the origin (if you want the magnitude of each column vector)

```
origin9 = zeros(9)
mags = colwise(Euclidean(), thousand9ds1, origin9)
#returns: 1000-element Array{Float64,1}
```

Other distances are also available:

- Squared Euclidean
- Cityblock
- Chebyshev
- Minkowski
- Hamming
- Cosine
- Correlation
- Chi-square
- Kullback-Leibler divergence
- Jensen-Shannon divergence
- Mahalanobis
- Squared Mahalanobis
- Bhattacharyya
- Hellinger

More details at the [package's github page here.](https://github.com/JuliaStats/Distances.jl)

Comment: +1 Thanks for bringing up the `Distances` package. I think OP's question is sufficiently answered by `norm()`, but it is useful to know of the package.

Comment: This also works for dimensions above 2 (norm only supports 1- or 2-dimensional arrays). E.g., `norm(rand((4,4,4)) - rand((4,4,4)))` will fail

Answer (score 0):

To compute the norm without any imports, simply

```
norm(x) = sqrt(sum(x.^2))
```

More generic for other L1, L2, L3, ... norms

```
norm(x; L=2) = sum(abs.(x).^L) ^ (1/L)
```

For Euclidean distance between two n-dimensional vectors just call `norm(x-y)`.

Comment: `sqrt(sum(x.^2))` creates an unnecessary intermediate array. Better to write `sqrt(sum(abs2, x))`